# Determine the coordinate of the given vector $ x $ with respect to $v_1, v_2, v_3$.

Tags: linear-algebra, vectors

Let $v_1 = (\frac{4}{13}, \frac{12}{13},\frac{-3}{13}) $, $v_2 = (\frac{12}{13}, \frac{-3}{13},\frac{4}{13})$
and $ v_3 = (\frac{3}{13}, \frac{-4}{13},\frac{-12}{13})$.

$(a)$ For $(i)$ and $(ii)$, determine the three coordinates of the given vector $ x$  with respect to $v_1, v_2, v_3$.

$(i) \space x= (1,-2,1)$.
I put $v_1, v_2, v_3$ and $x$ into an augmented matrix and then I reduced it to reduced row echelon form which yielded the coordinates $(\frac{25}{13}, \frac{10}{13}, \frac{17}{13})$.

I think this is correct.

For part $(ii) $ $ x= \sqrt5v_2 -\pi v_3 +10^{102}v_1$

I am not so sure what to do.
Do I sub $v_1, v_2, v_3$, in and then get an augmented matrix and reduce to RREF like I did for $(i)$?

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your approach to (i) is correct, but the result isn't. You can check this quite easily: if $\left(\frac{25}{13},\frac{10}{13},\frac{17}{13}\right)$ were the correct coordinates, then $x=\frac{25}{13}v_{1}+\frac{10}{13}v_{2}+\frac{17}{13}v_{3}$ would have to hold. I suspect you missed a sign somewhere.

Part (ii) is deceptively easy. Here, $x$ has already been written as a linear combination of $v_{1},v_{2}$, and $v_{3}$, so there are no computations to be done. The coordinates are simply $\left(10^{102},\sqrt{5},-\pi\right)$. (Note the order, which corresponds to the order in $(v_{1},v_{2},v_{3})$.)

Comment: thank you so much! I will check back over (i).

Comment: I tried (i) again and got (-17/13, 14/13, -23/13) but when when I times those coordinates by the vectors it does not give me x. I am not sure what I have done wrong.

Comment: That means you must have made some error in your calculations. 

Do you know about orthogonal matrices already? If you do, there is an alternative approach which is easier but only works in case the matrix $A$ which has columns $v_{1},v_{2},v_{3}$ (in that order) is orthogonal. Luckily, that's the case here.

So how does this work? Well, we are trying to find a $b$ such that $Ab=x$. As $A$ is orthogonal $A^{-1}=A^{T}$. Hence $b=A^{T}x$, which is relatively easy to compute.

Answer (score 1):

$x=√5v_2-\pi v_3 +10^{102}v_1$

$=10^{102}v_1+√5v_2+(-\pi) v_3$

Hence coordinate of $x$ relative to the basis $\{v_1, v_2, v_3\}$ is $(10^{102},√5,-\pi) $

Comment: great. thank you!